# Rails saving a file from a URL slower than straight Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, file, database

I have a Rails app that saves files in mongo. This works great and I have it set up to serve those files, but with some use cases I need to get the file and write it to disk (merging pdf files).

In IRB or from a simple Ruby file I can run the following code and get the file almost instantly, but when the same code is called from within Rails it times out.

```
require 'open-uri'

open('id1_front.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://127.0.0.1:3000/files/uploads/id1_front.pdf').read
  p file
end
```

-

```
Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error):
  app/controllers/design_controller.rb:38:in `block in save'
  app/controllers/design_controller.rb:37:in `save'
```

Anyone know why it would be timing out in Rails? Any alternate solutions to get a file out of mongo and write it to disk?

thanks!

Comment: I suspect a file deadlock. Just out of curiosity - I noticed the two filenames are the same (that you are writing to and that you are reading from). You're not trying to write to that same file on your filesystem that you're reading from, are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running your development server, you have only one thread on which to respond to requests. This thread will be blocked when a request is being served: so, you request design_controller#save, which then tries to make another request to the web server for an uploaded file. This request will never successfully complete, because the webserver is still trying to complete the previous one.

You might be able to get around this problem by using thin as your Rails server, instead of webrick. Add `gem thin` to your gemfile and start your server with `rails s thin`. I'm not sure if this will allow more than one request to be serviced simultaneously, but it's at least worth a shot.

--EDIT--

After some testing I determined that thin is also single-threaded, unfortunately, so will also have this exact same problem.

After a bit of Googling, I did discover [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun). It hasn't been active for awhile but it looks like it might fix your problem, since it spawns a new application per request in development. Give it a shot.